# Loop over csv files, output tail -n to new csv for each

Tags: bash, csv, tail

I am writing a bash script that loops over x number of logfiles and sends the most recent 10 entries for each logfile into a separate csv. So if I have 25 logfiles, after running the script I will expect to have 25 new csv files, each containing the 10 most recent lines.

Here is something along the lines of what I am trying to make:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /path/to/logs/*.log; 
    do tail -n 10 > "$file".csv
done
```

I can't seem to get it to loop over all the files - instead, it hangs on one. How do I get this small snippet to loop over each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the $file parameter in tail command. Could you try adding "$file" at the end of it?

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /path/to/logs/*.log; 
    do tail -n 10 "$file" > "$file".csv
done
```

Comment: Still not working, it says:

tail: cannot open '' for reading: No such file or directory

I think it reads the second "$file" as input instead of output

Comment: No luck:
+ for files in '~/path/to/logs/'
+ tail -n 10 ''
tail: cannot open '' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: can you paste the exact path you used and ls files under it.

Comment: Here is the ls for /Peaks/Data/ : [002.history  003.history  004.history  005.history  007.history  008.history  010.history  011.history  012.history]

And the path I have is ` for files in /~/Peaks/Data/*.history;
    do tail -n 10 "$file" > "$file".csv
done `

Comment: I think leaving the quotes in "$file" was taken too literally on my part. leaving it as just $file worked, definitely went over my head.